# Dropdown selected value to bind the DropDown next row inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdown

I have a Dropdown inside a gridview which is dynamic. What I want is after selecting the first value from the dropdown in the first row, using that selected value on the fist row bind the dropdown in the second row.

```
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Staff">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInsentiveCategory" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlInsentiveCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="InsentiveDataSource"
                                                DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="SalesStaffID">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator70" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlInsentiveCategory" 
                                                CssClass="rfv" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="0" ValidationGroup="group2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsentiveDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Connection %>"
                                                SelectCommand="SELECT '--Select--' as [Name],'0' as [SalesStaffID]  union all SELECT [Name],[SalesStaffID] FROM [SalesStaff] WHERE ([StaffCategoryID] = @StaffCategoryID)">
                                                <SelectParameters>
                                                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdnInsentiveCategoryID" Name="StaffCategoryID" PropertyName="Value"
                                                        Type="Int32" />
                                                </SelectParameters>
                                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnInsentiveCategoryID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("StaffCategoryID") %>' />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Help me to achieve this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this just using the SelectedIndexChanged event. The code is as follows. Hope this will help.

```
        protected void ddlInsentiveCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList ddlMainCategory = (DropDownList)gvInsentivePayment.Rows[0].FindControl("ddlInsentiveCategory");
        DropDownList ddlDependentCategory = (DropDownList)gvInsentivePayment.Rows[1].FindControl("ddlInsentiveCategory");

        if (ddlDependentCategory.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

            ddlMainCategoryValue = Convert.ToInt32(ddlMainCategory.SelectedValue);


            List<SalesStaff> FetchDependentList = // Bind the list using selected value from the 1st dropdown in the first row.


            ddlDependentCategory.DataSourceID = null; //Assigning null to remove the DatasourceID in client side.
            ddlDependentCategory.DataSource = FetchDependentList;
            ddlDependentCategory.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlDependentCategory.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlDependentCategory.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have potential failure point in your code. It will throw an exception when row 1 does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your gridview is also using a SqlDataSource, else there will be a small change required in approach mentioned.

- You need to add `Selecting` event to SqlDataSource for drop down list
  as in markup below.

  ```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="InsentiveDataSource" runat="server" 
             OnSelecting="InsentiveDataSource_Selecting" ....
  ```
- In code behind add the following C# code. The Selecting event for SqlDataSource of drop down is being subscribed to since it allows to make changes to SqlDataSource just before it gets the data.

  - Here, you are getting the selected value of drop down whose index has
    just been changed, and then getting the next row drop down control.
  - Once the next row drop down control is obtained, we simply call its
    `DataBind` method which will fire the Selecting event of its data
    source
  - and in the selecting event we can set the parameter value dynamically to previous row's drop down selected value.

    ```
    private int dropdpownValue;

    protected void ddlInsentiveCategory_SelectedIndexChanged ( object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {

     //get selected value of drop down and then find
     //the row index of this drop down control

     DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
     int.TryParse( (sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value, out ddlValue);
     GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) ddl.NamingContainer;
     int ddlRowIndex = row.RowIndex;

     //find the next row dropdownlist and if there is a next row,
     //then get this control and databind it

     GridView gridView =   (GridView)ddl.NamingContainer.NamingContainer ;
     if((ddlRowIndex + 1) <= (gridView.Rows.Count -1)) {
         DropDownList nextRowDDL = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView)ddl.NamingContainer.NamingContainer ).Rows[ ddlRowIndex + 1].FindControl("ddlInsentiveCategory")
         nextRowDDL.DataBind();
       }
    }

    protected void InsentiveDataSource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
       if(dropdpownValue> 0) {
              e.Command.Parameters[0].Value=  dropdpownValue;
              dropdownValue = 0;
       }
    }
    ```

Comment: really appreciate your solution. I was able to solve this using less steps as I posted in my answer